# How to add slide up animation on dynamic element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have one div and one button.

on click of button i am appending a another div.
after appending the second div i want to add slide up to first div and slide down to second with jquery animation method.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="user">
        <div class="closed_div">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="addDiv">Add open Div</button>
</div>
```

Now i am appending the new div with below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.addDiv').click(function(){
                var html = '<div class="open_div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and \n\
                        typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys \n\
                        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type \n\
                        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining \n\
                        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, \n\
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>';
                $('.user').append(html);
            });
        });
```

and animation with following code

```
$(".closed_div").animate({height:'100%','opacity':1},1500);
$(".open_div").animate({height:0},1500);
```

But its not working well.Can you suggest me what am i doing wrong.

Thnakyou.

Comment: Did you try slideUp() and slideDown() instead of animate()? Looks like you missed a "." in front of open_div in $("open_div").animate({height:0},1500);

Comment: Yes i have tried slideUp and slideDown. and i have missed a dot in question. not in real

Comment: On appending the the new div, you want to hide the old div by slideup and show the new div by slidedown. right?

Comment: Yes absolutely right buddy.

Comment: Well. In that case I have provided a solution exactly displaying that functionality

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that uses the jQuery slideUp and slideDown functions. I remove the divs that are slid up. Height:100% is the issue with animation sometimes.

```js
let counter = 0;

$('.addDiv').click(function() {
  var html = $('<div class="closed_div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and \n\
                        typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys \n\
                        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type \n\
                        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining \n\
                        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, \n\
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.' + counter++ + '</div>');
  $('.user div').slideUp(300, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
  });             
  $('.user').append(html);
  html.slideDown();
  
});
```

```css
.closed_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="user">
    <div class="open_div" style="display:none;">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="addDiv">Add open Div</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".closed_div").animate({height:'100%','opacity':1},1500);  
  $(function () {
   $('.addDiv').click(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        $('.user').after('<div class="open_div none">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and \n\
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys \n\
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type \n\
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining \n\
essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, \n\
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>').next('div').slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
.none{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="user">
        <div class="closed_div">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="addDiv">Add open Div</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set display none property to the newly appended `open_div`, add `closed_div` class to the last opened div. Then hide the last closed_div using `slideUp`. Inside the callback of the slideUp, `slideDown` the last `open_div`.

And in your css, you need to set `display: none` property to `open_div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.addDiv').click(function(){
                var html = '<div class="open_div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and \n\
                        typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys \n\
                        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type \n\
                        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining \n\
                        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, \n\
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>';
                $('.open_div:last').addClass('closed_div');
                $('.user').append(html);
                $('.closed_div:last').slideUp("slow", function() {
                 $('.open_div:last').slideDown("slow");
                });
            });
        });
```

```css
.open_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="user">
        <div class="closed_div">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="addDiv">Add open Div</button>
</div>
```